# how to launch another activity from fragment with putting chosen member info into extras?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

Here is the first page that contents fragment activity_fpage.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/gymView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/arnold"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/appIcon"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/newUser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/arnold"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:minWidth="288dip"
    android:text="@string/newUser" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmet_user_list"
    android:name="com.example.gym1_1.ListOfUsers"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/newUser" />
```

next is the java file for fragment

```
    import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class ListOfUsers extends ListFragment implements OnClickListener {

  String data[] = new String[] { "Matt", "Ken", "July", "Trish" };

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),com.example.gym1_1.MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

but the main class where the shown layout launches is

```
public class First_page extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fpage);
    }
```

The question is how to make "Matt", "Ken", "July", "Trish" clickable, by clicking which user would be sent to the next activity with with clicked name put in extras?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to Override the method

```
public void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
```

then, with the position, get the choosen name from your array, and then pass it to the intent. Something like:

```
 @Override
 public void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
     Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),com.example.gym1_1.MainActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("name", data[position]);
     startActivity(intent);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),com.example.gym1_1.MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("name_key",chosenName); // get the chosenName as a String from your widget with names
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Well in such composition Intent doesn't work, the other answer is the right one, however thanks for the attention

Comment: Explain please how could it be that "`Intent` doesn't work" comparing to accepted answer if the only difference is a source of value in `intent.putExtra()`? The only your problem I can see here is that you don't understand how to get the chosen value from your name picker to pass it as `chosenName`. You could get it from the view actually.

Comment: You misunderstood, or I explained it not so well. When I launch the code I shown here buttons in the list does not bring me to the next activity.
Renan proposed to override another method
public void onListItemClick