# New activity displaying info based on the item selected in list view

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm working on an app that pulls information from a news-feed server. Right now I have a list of latest articles from the site that pulls in a title, date, image and some information. This is what I have:

```
    public class NewsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private NewsModel model = NewsModel.getInstance();
    private NewsListFragment fragment;

public NewsListAdapter(NewsListFragment fragment){
    super();
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView title;
    private TextView short_info;
    private TextView date;
    private NetworkImageView image_url;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        // Update the details
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        short_info = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.short_info);
        date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        image_url = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_url);
        // Set default image when the image is loading
        image_url.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.download);
        // Set error image if there is an error
        image_url.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.error);

        // Click listener
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                fragment.onItemClicked(getPosition());
            }
        });
    }

    public void setData(News news){
        // Set values
        title.setText(news.getTitleName());
        short_info.setText(news.getShort_info() + "...");
        date.setText("Posted on " + news.getDate());
        image_url.setImageUrl(news.getImage_url(), NewsApp.getInstance().getImageLoader());
    }
}

public NewsListAdapter() {
    super();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    // Create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_news_item, viewGroup, false);
    // Save the view in the view holder
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    // Return the view holder
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
// Get the relevant object
    News news = model.getNewsArrayList().get(i);
    //Populate the view
    viewHolder.setData(news);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return model.getNewsArrayList().size();
}
}
```

When an item is selected a new activity starts. What I'm having problems with is loading information into the new activity from the previous news item selected. I know that I need to use the "News" object that I have to populate the UI with the right values. The new activity will show the title, date, info and image too. I would really appreciate any help.

```
public class NewsDetailsFragment extends Fragment {

public void updateDetails(int id){

    News news = NewsModel.getInstance().getNewsArrayList().get(id);

    // Update the UI with data
}

public NewsDetailsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_details, container, false);

    return view;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let your `News` implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html), then put the `News` object in a Fragment bundle when [creating the Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#BackStack).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your `News` object via `Bundle` in `Intent` to your details activity. to do that your `News` class has to implement `Serializable` or `Parcellable`. Or you could pass the only id same way.
[Take a look for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773339/how-to-launch-another-activity-from-fragment-with-putting-chosen-member-info-int/29773440)

Comment: public void onItemClicked(int position){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewsDetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("ITEM_ID", position);
        startActivity(intent);} I have this code already but the question is how to update the UI in the new activity? I know it needs to be modified in the "updateDetails" and also wired in the "onCreateView" but not sure how to do so?

Comment: I can't figure out: you are talking about `NewsDetailsActivity`  but you have `NewsDetailsFragment` which is not an `Activity` but `Fragment`. To pass something to a `Fragment` you should use `setArguments()` and in `Fragment` you could get it back using `getArguments()`. Both methods works with `Bundle` just like `Activity` `Intent` does.